# Atmospheric correction for RapideEye without atmospheric parameters

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing, digital-image-processing, orfeo-toolbox

I'd like to perform an atmospheric correction of my RapidEye images but metadata do no include atmospheric parameters required to use the 6s algo implemented in the Orfeo ToolBox. Is there a solution to still apply the corrections?

Browsing on the web, I found that in grass it was possible not to specify them (http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/i.atcorr.html) but rather define if the site is midlatitude summer, midlatitude winter, subarctic summer, subarctic winter, etc. Do those areas have predefined parameters and if yes where can I find them?

Comment: Atmospheric Correction RAPP Fig. A-9.Detailed flow chart for atmospheric correction mode.  http://6s.ltdri.org/6S_code2_thiner_stuff/6S_Manual_Part_1.pdf (Page 45)

Comment: You state "metadata do no include atmospheric parameters required to use the 6s algo...". Can you be more precise? Which are the parameters you are missing? At least, for GRASS GIS' `i.atcorr` module, everything required is explained in the manual and the source for most is the date & time of the acquisition itself, the location which the image represents, etc. If you provide more details, it will be easier to get to the solution.

Comment: I mean that I have all the information on the zenithal and azimuthal viewing angles, the day of acquisition but nothing on the water vapor, the ozone and the aerosol amount...

Comment: Did you check http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Atmospheric_correction#Sources_for_AOD_estimations? See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66896/open-source-alternatives-to-erdas-atcor/74190#74190

Comment: Thanks for the link. Does anyone know how to get the MODTRAN look up tables?