# Atmospheric correction for Landsat 8 in ERDAS?

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, landsat-8

I am attempting to run some classification on Landsat 8 imagery, however, I need to perform atmospheric correction on the images in order to reveal true spectral signatures. I am using ERDAS, and the autonomous atmospheric correction tool does not support the Landsat 8 sensor. Unfortunately, I do not have access to ENVI which supports landsat 8, or a licence to ATCOR, which seems to be a ERDAS add on for atmospheric correction.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to upgrade to Erdas 2013 where ATCOR supports the Landsat-8 OLI sensor.  There is a supporting document [here](http://geospatial.intergraph.com/Libraries/Tech_Docs/ATCOR_Product_Description.sflb.ashx) which provides specific details.

You may also be interested in the following thread: [Open Source Alternatives to Erdas ATCOR](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/66896/8104).

Comment: Hi, just to follow up, I have upgraded to ERDAS 2014, however, my issue lies in that I do not have access to ATCOR as it does not come licensed with ERDAS. Is GRASS my best bet?

Answer (score 1):

AAIC is an autonomous atmospheric correction application that works with most commercial mulitspectral sensors.  The process was developed by Applied Analysis Inc. (AAI) and is distributed as an add-on by BAE Systems for SOCET GXP and Intergraph for IMAGINE.  Both companies versions will support LandSat 8 imagery with their 2015 releases. Although the application is not free, both companies offer no-cost evaluation copies if you are a current user of their software. Academic license are also available at a greatly reduced price. More information on AAIC is available at the distributors webpage and at AAI's webpage www.discoveraai.com, including detailed technical white paper with test results.

If you take the time to contact the AAIC distributors you may also want to ask for a demonstration license of GeoPalette, which is an autonomous land material identification/classification and bathymetry  application.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [6s](http://6s.ltdri.org/) in the VNIR-SWIR bands. You need some information from the metadata. Then you get the equations to apply atmospheric correction. It is free!.